EJS not being recognized as a file type in WebStorm even after plugin and npm install
I am working on a node.js project and need to use EJS. I'm using WebStorm and the problem is it doesn't recognize that file and treats it like a text file, even after I installed the WebStorm EJS plugin and npm I ejs
I really need assistance, much help is greatly appreciated.


Have you asked the JetBrains support?
